# Necking point in a Stress-Strain plot

Tags: stress-strain

Why doesn't the necking start after the yield point but starts from the point of maximum tensile stress in a stress strain curve? Volume being constant during elongation, the reduction in area should start after the yield point, right?

Answer (score 2):

As a wire is stretched the tension in the wire increases with length - up to a maximum tension. During this stage there may be a reduction in the diameter of the wire, but it will be fairly small.

After the maximum tension is reached the tension in the wire *decreases* as the length increases, so there are two different lengths which produce the same tension. Part of the wire will shorten (decreasing its strain) and a different part will lengthen (increasing its strain) in order to reduce the tension force. The lengthened part may lengthen by a lot, as the rest of the wire shortens, so its diameter will decrease very noticeably compared with the rest of the wire.

Comment: Firstly, Thank you for the answer. Is there any name for this concept so that I can go through it? Since I'm hearing this for the first time that "After the maximum tension is reached the tension in the wire decreases as the length increases, so there are two different lengths which produce the same tension. Part of the wire will shorten (decreasing its strain) and a different part will lengthen (increasing its strain) in order to reduce the tension force".

Comment: I don't know of any specific name, other than perhaps necking. In more general terms the uniform state stops being the stable state. Perhaps the idea of functions with more than one value might be helpful (even though mathematicians don't call them functions). When you look at the stress/strain graph (or a force extension graph) you see where the graph reaches the top of the curve and starts to turn down; that is what shows that two strains give the same stress (or two local lengths give the same tension).